# Ruby on Rails & Heroku で作った静的ページが facebook canvas で表示できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, facebook-api

facebook の canvas アプリとして Ruby on Rails & Heroku で作ったページを試しに表示してみたいなと思っているのですが、真っ白しか出ません。
わざと存在しないページを設定すると404ページが表示されてくれるので、script を書かなくても表示できるような気がするのですが、検索しても古そうな情報ばかりでちんぷんかんぷんです。

routes.rb に

```
  post "canvas_test"                   => "pootalo#canvas_test"
```

を追加

layouts/canvas_test.html.erb に

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: green;
}
--> 
</style>
canvas test 2
</body>
</html>
```

view のほうの canvas_test.html.erb は空

あとコントローラーに

```
  def canvas_test
    render :layout => 'canvas_test'
  end
```

を追加

さらに application_controller.rb で

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

をコメントアウトしています。

ちゃんと https でリクエストしています。

これどうやったら表示できるようになるかご存知の方いますでしょうか？
もしくは、私が根本的な勘違いをしているのか？
アドバイスよろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://teratail.com/questions/11343
teratailで質問したら解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

まずはHerokuにアクセスが飛んでいるのか確認してみましょう。

```
heroku logs --tail
```

もしアクセスできていればログが出ますし、エラーが出ていればそれで解決できるはずです。アクセスが来ていなければFacebookアプリがHerokuにアクセスできていないということになります。

Comment: それは確認してます。たしかにアクセスはあるようなんです。